# Android multiple and dynamically images aligned

Tags: android, image, layout

Right now, I have a RecyclerView and multiple CardView to show my items.

My CardView have a RelativeLayout where I add some ImageViews (in this case 3, but can be more).

Each of my items will have a list of images to show, lets suppose #item1 have Facebook, Twitter and Youtube, but #item2 just have Facebook and Youtube images.

How should I align the images? If I just remove Twitter image, I need to update layout_toLeftOf of my Facebook image to Youtube image.

I think I shouldn't do this kind of logic to all my items, it will be over power...

Example image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJZTi.png

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/coverImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|top">
                <ImageView android:background="@null"
                    android:id="@+id/facebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook_icon"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/twitter"/>
                <ImageView android:background="@null"
                    android:id="@+id/twitter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/twitter_icon"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/youtube"/>
                <ImageView android:background="@null"
                    android:id="@+id/youtube"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/youtube_icon"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to work with LinearLayout in this case and use layout_alignParentRight and layout_alignParentTop="true" instead of android:layout_gravity="end|top" like below :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
                <ImageView android:background="@null"
                    android:id="@+id/facebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook_icon"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <ImageView android:background="@null"
                    android:id="@+id/twitter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/twitter_icon"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <ImageView android:background="@null"
                    android:id="@+id/youtube"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/youtube_icon"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hmm, looks fine! I should add all the ImageViews I want on XML and work in JAVA to delete the ImageViews I do not want? Because some items do not have all the images...

Comment: you can set the visibility "gone" in the code or statically in xml. ( android:visibility="gone" ) I don't really see your problem

Comment: I used LinearLayout as you told me, but android:layout_gravity="end|top" didn't work. I kept the other settings. Ty

Comment: please use layout_alignParentRight and layout_alignParentTop="true" instead of android:layout_gravity="end|top"..like above

Comment: because it didn't work with layout_gravity="end|top"

Comment: It actually worked with  layout_gravity="end|top" and did not work with your settings..

Answer (score 0):

You should use LinearLayout with Horizontal Orientation !

```
<LinearLayout
 ...
  android:orientation="horizontal">

    //ImageViews in priority order

</LinearLayout>
```